# Python - Eliminate index values from Pandas output

Tags: python, excel, pandas, indexing

**CODE SAMPLE**

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv',parse_dates=True)
print(data['EmpName'])
```

**Output:**

```
**0**     Tim K
**1**     Joesph R
**2**     Don T
**3**     Rachel P
**4**     Sam W
```

Want to eliminate index values from the output?

Comment: But why? The index is an important part of the `pandas` library and every `Series` and `DataFrame` is required to have one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print out a list of names use:

```
for i in data['EmpName']:
    print(i)
```

Outputs:

```
Tim K
Joseph R
...
```

If you need the data in a list use:

```
new_list = list(data['EmpName'])
```

#### Final note

Print statement formatting is somewhat arbitrary. Usually the print function is used to test objects during development. You should familiarize yourself with common python objects such as lists, tuples, numpy arrays and pandas dataframes, to enable you to manipulate data effectively.

Comment: You misspelled "Joesph".

Comment: Its perfectly worked, now the problem is. I have two columns (EmpName, EmpCity) and want to eliminate the index value. Can you please help ?

Answer (score 0):

`data['EmpName']` is a Pandas Series. If you do `list([data['EmpName'])`, that will print it out as a list; it will be enclosed in brackets and the elements will be separated with commas. So it will look like this: `['Tim K', 'Joesph R', 'Don T', 'Rachel P', 'Sam W']`. If you don't want the commas, you can do `' '.join(data['EmpName'])` and that will give `'Tim K Joesph R Don T Rachel P Sam W'`. Note that if any of the elements are not string-type (e.g. some are int), that will give an error, so to be safe you might want to do `' '.join([name for name in data['EmpName']])`